# display text prefix only if data is present

Tags: angularjs

I have some AngularJS code that displays an outstanding balance only if their is a balance to display.

```
{{Customer.LastName}}, {{Customer.FirstName}} ${{Customer.OutstandingBalance}}
```

What I would like to do is not display the dollar sign ($) at all if there is no outstanding balance. How do I make the dollar sign dependent on the value of `Customer.OutstandingBalance`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think except obvious suggestions like "wrap it in `<span ng-show="Customer.OutstandingBalance">`

you could do smth like this: `{{Customer.LastName}}, {{Customer.FirstName}} {{Customer.OutstandingBalance ? '$' : ''}}{{Customer.OutstandingBalance}}`

Answer (score 3):

Use custom filter with inbuilt currency filer.

```
app.filter('myCurrency', function($filter){
  return function(input){
    return input ? $filter('currency')(input) : '';
  };
});
```

in view use

```
{{Customer.LastName}}, {{Customer.FirstName}} {{Customer.OutstandingBalance | myCurrency}}
```

Here's plunker demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/ocqmiz4tNX49R8rG8VA7?p=preview

Comment: a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) will be needed to hide the dollar sign.

Comment: @MamaWalter is correct need to use some custom filer. Angular inbuilt currency alone won't help. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could have a span that only is showed based on the `OutstandingBalance`:

```
<span ng-show="Customer.OutstandingBalance != 0">$</span> {{Customer.OutstandingBalance}}
```